# How override calendar portlet in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I am using liferay 6.1 CE and I want to override `remiderUser` method for event in calender portlet.
I have tried to find but I found the way to override `CalEventLocalService` but I didn't find any method which sending the `eventReminder` to user.

I have gone through following links.

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-a-portal-service-using-a-hook
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/29120467
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/29120467

**Updated**

Following class I have created and I am trying to override the `checkEvents` method

```
public class MyCalEventServiceImple extends CalEventLocalServiceWrapper {

    public MyCalEventServiceImple(CalEventLocalService calEventLocalService) {
        super(calEventLocalService);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public CalEvent addEvent(
            long userId, String title, String description, String location,
            int startDateMonth, int startDateDay, int startDateYear,
            int startDateHour, int startDateMinute, int endDateMonth,
            int endDateDay, int endDateYear, int durationHour,
            int durationMinute, boolean allDay, boolean timeZoneSensitive,
            String type, boolean repeating, TZSRecurrence recurrence,
            int remindBy, int firstReminder, int secondReminder,
            ServiceContext serviceContext)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {

        // Event
            System.out.println("*****************CALLED Success.....**********");


        return null;
    }


}
```

but not found any way to achieve this.

Anyone can help??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the liferay source code `remindUser` (which is protected) is the method that sends reminder to user about events. If you dig more into the liferay source code you can find that `checkEvents` (which is public) is the method which ultimately calls `remindUser` method. So, I think you can use `checkEvents` method for your requirement.

EDIT : You can use service wrapper hook to override liferay service classes. [Service Wrapper Hook](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-a-portal-service-using-a-hook)

[liferay source](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repo1.maven.org%24maven2@com.liferay.portal%24portal-impl@6.2.0@com%24liferay%24portlet%24calendar%24service%24impl@CalEventLocalServiceImpl@remindUser%28com.liferay.portlet.calendar.model.CalEvent%2Ccom.liferay.portal.model.User%2Cjava.util.Calendar%2Cjava.util.Calendar%29&k=u)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please let me know how can I override/access checkEvents method using hook?

Comment: I have already done this but I am not able to find checkEvents in CalEventLocalServiceWrapper class which I am extending in my custom class.

Comment: looks OK. Can you please type checkEvents and press ctrl + space and check if you get suggestions related to checkEvents method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81529/discussion-between-lucky-boy-and-ranjitsinh).

Comment: In which jsp does the CalEventLocalServiceWrapper class was used ?